# Is there a way to pass a return double from a Child Component function, to a Parent component but in all page?

Tags: c#, frontend, blazor, blazor-webassembly

Im new into BlazorWA and i can't get the right way to send data/parameters from child to parent components. Is there a way to pass a return value from a Child Component Function to Parent Component?

Child Component Detail:

```
 [Parameter] public double TotalPrice { get; set; }
 [Parameter] protected EventCallback<double> ReturnValue { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
    {
        FileDetail = blabla;

        CalculateCancelleds(TotalPrice);
    }

 public double CalculateCancelleds(double x)
    {
        var total = 0.0;

        var cancelledsToList = FileDetail.Where(x => x.StatusStr == "Cancelled").Select(x => x.Net).ToList();

        var totalCancelledNet = cancelledsToList.Sum(net => total + net);

        var result = x - totalCancelledNet;

        return result;

    }
```

Parent Component:

```
  <td class="table-Net">$@objItem.Price @* **Instead the total price, Here i want to get the result calculation from Child Compononent Function "CalculateCancelleds()"***@ </td>

<ChildComponent.ReservationDetail TotalPrice="@objItem.Price" **<-----Here im sending the total price to Child Component.** Enix="@objItem.Enix" Admin="@objUser.Admin" FileStatus="@objItem.StatusString">
</ChildComponentReservationDetail.ReservationDetail>
```

I try with blazor data binding documentation from microsoft but i can't get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a very simple example that demonstrates how to use binding to achieve what you want.

*PriceCalculator.razor*

```cs
<h3>PriceCalculator</h3>
<div class="alert alert-primary m-3">
    Value = @this.Value
</div>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick=this.IncrementPrice>Increment Price</button>

@code {
    [Parameter] public decimal Value { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<decimal> ValueChanged { get; set; }

    private async Task IncrementPrice()
        =>  await ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(this.Value + 4);
}
```

*Index.razor*

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<PriceCalculator @bind-Value=this.model.TotalPrice />

<div class="alert alert-info m-3">
Value = @this.model.TotalPrice
</div>

@code {
    private MyModel model = new();

    public class MyModel
    {
        public decimal TotalPrice { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And a more complex `PriceCalculator`.

```cs
<h3>PriceCalculator</h3>
<div class="alert alert-primary m-3">
    Value = @this.value
</div>

<div class="m-2">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick=this.IncrementPrice>Increment Price</button>
    <button class="btn btn-success" @onclick=this.Save>Save Price</button>
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter] public decimal Value { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<decimal> ValueChanged { get; set; }

    private decimal value;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
        => value = this.Value;

    private Task IncrementPrice()
    {
        value = value + 4;
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private async Task Save()
        => await ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(this.value);
}
```